# how to make a (récursive?) Custom Deserialization

Tags: java, json, object

I am using a custom deserialisation, but  i will need a better brain to solve this than mine.

to simplify :
i have one json file, one entity, one deserialization class, and a main

focus on EntityDeserialization ( searchEntitie function who take as param entities) and Main (entities variable)

Entity.json
(rootEntity is an Entity object)

```
[
  {
    "name": "BFA",
    "entityType": "secteur",
    "rootEntity": ""

  },
    {
    "name": "IT",
    "entityType": "service",
    "rootEntity": ""

  },
  {
    "name": "EX",
    "entityType": "offre",
    "rootEntity": "BFA"
  }
]
```

Entity class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = EntityDeserialization.class)
public class Entity {
    private String name;
    private String entityType;
    private Entity rootEntity;
```

EntityDeserialization

```
 public Entity deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String name =  node.get("name").asText();
        String entitype = node.get("entityType").asText();
        String rootEntity = node.get("rootEntity").asText();
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity = entity.searchEntity(entities, rootEntity);
        return new Entity(name, entitype,entity);
    }
```

Main

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        TypeReference<List<User>> typeReferenceUser = new TypeReference<>() {};
        TypeReference<List<Entity>> typeReferenceEntity = new TypeReference<>() {};
        FileInputStream inputStreamUser = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\oraph\\Desktop\\user.json");
        FileInputStream inputStreamEntity = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\oraph\\Desktop\\entity.json");
        try {
           List<User> users = mapper.readValue(inputStreamUser,typeReferenceUser);
           List<Entity> entities = mapper.readValue(inputStreamEntity,typeReferenceEntity);
...
```

Here the problemes :
I attend to use my function in EntityDeserialization `searchEntity(List entity, String rootEntity)`  which is in the main and to be in the process of fill up.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way, with two successives deserialization. One to fill a Entity list, and second to build ENtity object with that list.

Comment: Cleaner way of doing this is to do it with 2 parses. In the first parse build entity objects and store them in the map of <name, Entity>. In the second parse iterate over all the entities are create mappings between root and child entities.